# Cancelling shutdown -h command on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, terminal, terminal.app

I usually use the command `sudo shutdown -h +60` from the Terminal on my Mac. Although I'd like sometime to cancel the scheduled shutdown or postpone it. Is there a command to do so? If yes, how?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try using:

`sudo killall shutdown`